# Create YB DB and Schemas via a Script file

Tags: yugabytedb

Yugabyte,

is there a way I can create the YB DB and it's schema by running one script file with all the commands mentioned here (https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/explore/ysql/#docker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute queries with `ysqlsh` from the command line using `-c`, example we use that to create the database:

```
./bin/ysqlsh -c 'create database ybdemo;'
```

You can also execute sql scripts with ysqlsh using `-f` (https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/ysqlsh/#f-filename-file-filename), example:

```
./bin/ysqlsh -d ybdemo -f share/schema.sql
```

This will execute the `schema.sql` script into `ybdemo` database. And repeat that for every `.sql` file.

Comment: Thank you Dorian. This worked.

Now I need to add these two below commands into a docker file and run itself when I create a container. 

docker exec -it yb1 /home/yugabyte/bin/ysqlsh -c 'create database ybdemo;'
docker exec -it yb1 /home/yugabyte/bin/ysqlsh -d ybdemo -f share/schema.sql

I also asked this here https://forum.yugabyte.com/t/create-yb-db-and-schemas-via-a-script-file/991/11